# How to use Hovertool for multiple lines?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have the following code:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year = [1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
    pop_pakistan = [44.91, 58.09, 78.07, 107.7, 138.5, 170.6]
    pop_india = [449.48, 553.57, 696.783, 870.133, 1000.4, 1309.1]

    output_file('line.html', mode='inline')
    plot = figure(title='Population Graph of India and Pakistan', x_axis_label='Year',
                  y_axis_label='Population in million')

    source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        year=year,
        population=[pop_pakistan, pop_india],
    ))
    print(source1.data)

    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = """
    <div style=padding=5px>Data</div>
    """
    plot.add_tools(hover)
    plot.line(year, pop_pakistan, line_width=2, line_color='green', legend='Pakistan')
    plot.circle(year, pop_pakistan, fill_color="green", line_color='green', size=8)
    plot.line(year, pop_india, line_width=2, line_color='orange', legend='India')
    plot.circle(year, pop_india, fill_color="orange", line_color='orange', size=8)
    show(plot)
```

I want to show data on hover. I m getting the following warning

`BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('population', 2), ('year', 6)`

How to use Hovertool for multiple Y-axis?

Thanks

**Update**

Based on the answer by @bigreddot, I made the following changes:

```
plot.line('year', 'pop_pakistan', line_width=2, line_color='green', legend='Pakistan', source=source)
    plot.circle('year', 'pop_pakistan', fill_color="green", line_color='green', size=8, source=source)

    plot.line('year', 'pop_india', line_width=2, line_color='orange', legend='India', source=source)
    plot.circle('year', 'pop_india', fill_color="orange", line_color='orange', size=8, source=source)
    show(plot)
```

But I am unable to show relevant hover data for respective country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is because the lengths of the columns in your `ColumnDataSource` are not all the same. A `ColumnDataSource` is a tabular structure similar to a Pandas `DataFrame`. It does not make sense for there to be columns of different lengths. In your case, you have:

```
year = [1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010] # length 6
```

and

```
population = [pop_pakistan, pop_india] # length 2
```

Presumably, you want:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    year=year,
    pop_pakistan=pop_pakistan, 
    pop_india=pop_india
))
```

Which would create a CS with three columns, all of length 6.

Then, the next observation is that you are creating the CDS, but never actually using it. To use a data source, you have to actually pass it to the glyph functions, and refer to the columns by name, e.g.

```
# pass the source argument and refer to columns by name (strings)

plot.line('year', 'pop_pakistan', source=source, ...)
plot.circle('year', 'pop_pakistan, source=source, ...)

plot.line('year', 'pop_india', source=source, ...)
plot.circle('year', 'pop_india', source=source, ...)
```

Finally, your tooltip specification does not do anything, except always print the same text `"Data"` and nothing else. Typically you you would want to use the `@` syntax to show values from the data source, e.g. `"@year"` ot `"@pop_india" somewhere inside the tooltip text. See the [HoverTool documenatation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool) for more information.

Comment: I managed to access variables from the source but they are showing Pakistan population data on India line too. How do I let Tooptip know about it that if I am hovering on Pakistan it shows Pakistan data only? I put the code on the main question.

Comment: OK I was able to solve by taking different source variables with same key and then using them in Hover. Thanks!